# Double If's with a possible And

Tags: microsoft-excel

I one cell I am trying to determine if a bonus will be paid at full, half or none based on the data from two other cells on a different sheet. These are the two IFs that I have and they both work on their own but I cannot figure out how to combine them.

=IF('[August SC Manual Input.xlsx]sample'!$L$4=1,(N4/2),(N4*1)) This is the Half

=IF('[August SC Manual Input.xlsx]sample'!$M$4=1,(N4*0),(N4*1)) This is the None

If the condition of both cells is bank then the result needs to be full.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One goes in the false of the other:

```
=IF('[August SC Manual Input.xlsx]sample'!$L$4=1,(N4/2),IF('[August SC Manual Input.xlsx]sample'!$M$4=1,(N4*0),(N4*1)))
```

Comment: @nntimm1 please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.  It is something only the one who posed the question can do.